# php: preg_match / preg_replace word with space inside

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

Hi I would like to match & replace a word in a text also if splitted by spaces.

IE:

I would like to match "foobar" also if it's written "foo bar", "fo obar" or "foob ar"

Constraints:
The word is not "static" so I cannot write a preg_replace like:

```
preg_replace("/f\s*o\s*o\s*b\s*a\s*r/", "my_replace", $string)
```

The word is not alone, and does not have a specific position in the text so it can be placed like
"bla bla fo obar bla bla"

Comment: remove spaces and then do match ;)

Comment: @Robert: He doesn't want to do a match but a replace.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the word you are trying to search and replace and generate a regex statement:

```
$text="bla bla foo b ar bla bla";

$search = "foobar";

$preg = "";
for($i=0;$i<strlen($search);$i++)
{
    $preg.=substr($search, $i, 1)." *?";
}

echo preg_replace("/$preg/i", "TEST", $text);
```

Comment: In which way is this regex better than OP's one? Yours doesn't work if there are more than one space between letters. Moreover, the word foobar is an example, it must be dynamic

Comment: I edited my example so that it will work with any number of spaces separating the letters.  This will work with any word you are looking for, just need to change the letters and put a space and *? after each one.

Comment: I realize now that the word needed to be dynamic like you said, I didn't get that when I first read it.  But my solution now works with any word you give it.

Comment: `str_split` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) does the same than your `for` loop with `substr`. Note that this function (like the way you use) doesn't support multibyte encoded characters (it splits the string byte by byte).

Comment: if you want to handle multibytes strings, you should use `preg_split` with the `u` modifier.